How can I access the value of my variable and use the variable's value in another page
This is my variable( String activeTitle) from the Widget BarGraph.
class BarGraph extends StatefulWidget {
  final List totalCrabs;

  const BarGraph({super.key, required this.totalCrabs});

  @override
  State<BarGraph> createState() => _BarGraphState();
}

class _BarGraphState extends State<BarGraph> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    late List<double> graphData;
    late String graphTitle;
    
    String activeTitle = '';

I want to use the value of this variable in another Widget
InfoCard(
  title: "Scylla Serrata",
  value: scyllaSerrataCount.toString(),
  topColor: Colors.brown,
  isActive: activeTitle == "Scylla Serrata",
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      activeTitle = "Scylla Serrata";
    });
  },
),

How do I connect them?

You can do it in two ways. 1) Make the variable static and access like BarGraph. activeTitle, 2) By Instance Variables of class like BarGraph barGraph = BarGraph(); barGraph.activeTitle .

is this InfoCard shown inside BarGraph? From where are you creating the InfoCard ?

from another page Widget which is the HomePage

If BarGraph and InfoCard are displayed on different pages in our app then you need some kind of app state management to store and retrieve the variable activeTitle. A list of state management approaches can be found in the flutter documentation.

I would recommend having a look at riverpod and its (optional) code generation tools. With this approach your
app could become reactive, that is as soon as activeTitle changes the widgets that depend on this variable will rebuild.
As a start, your app would be wrapped in an instance of ProviderScope:
runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));

and you would have e.g. a provider in a file active_title_provider.dart:
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class ActiveTitleNotifier extends Notifier<String> {
  @override
  String build() {
    // Return an initial value for activeTitle
    return '';
  }

  /// Set the current notifier state.
  void set(String value) {
    state = value;
  }
}

final activeTitleProvider = NotifierProvider<ActiveTitleNotifier, String>(
  () => ActiveTitleNotifier(),
);

Your class BarGraph would become a ConsumerStatefulWidget that has access to ref(used to access providers):
class BarGraph extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final List totalCrabs;

  const BarGraph({super.key, required this.totalCrabs});

  @override
  ConsumerState<BarGraph> createState() => _BarGraphState();
}

class _BarGraphState extends ConsumerState<BarGraph> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    late List<double> graphData;
    late String graphTitle;
    
    // Retrieve the current value of `activeTitle` and watch its value. 
    // The widget will be rebuild if `activeTitle` changes.  
    final activeTitle = ref.watch(activeTitleProvider);

Finally the widget that contains your InfoCard should be a ConsumerWidget or StatefulConsumerWidget and in its build method you would have:
InfoCard(
  title: "Scylla Serrata",
  value: scyllaSerrataCount.toString(),
  topColor: Colors.brown,
  isActive: activeTitle == "Scylla Serrata",
  onTap: () {
      // Sets the current value of `activeTitle`.  
      ref.read(activeTitleProvider.notifier).set('Scylla Serrata');
  },
),

